# Blazor Server App How to implement master-detail Blazor page with multiple edits

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor-server-side, master-detail, radzen

I am working on a Blazor Server App project. I want to implement a master-detail blazor page having multiple inline edits something similar to the example below?

[master detail sample](https://demo.aspnetawesome.com/MasterDetailCrudDemo#Master-Detail-CRUD-using-Inline-Editing-and-nesting)

I checked some open-source third-party components which are available for **free** like MudBlazor but unfortunately, there is no master detail component. The closest component is the MudTable which has an inline edit mode. ([MudTable sample](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/mOwGkVaGKYDagXzz))

I would appreciate your help, thanks in advance.

### Edit

Radzen does what I want with master detail hierarchy :)

```
<RadzenDataGrid EditMode="DataGridEditMode.Multiple">
```

### Edit2

Here are my order and order detail entities and related codes.

```
public class Order
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        
        [Required]
        public DateTime OrderDateTime { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(250)]
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(250)]
        public string VendorName { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string DoneBy { get; set; }
        public List<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }


    }

public class OrderDetail
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string ProductCode { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(250)]
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int BuyQuantity { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int SellQuantity { get; set; }
        public double CostRatio { get; set; }
        public double UnitCost { get; set; }
        public double TotalBuyPrice { get; set; }
        public double TotalSellPrice { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(150)]
        public string ShippingNumber { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(150)]
        public string TrackingNumber { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(400)]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int OrderId { get; set; }
        public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
    }
public interface IOrderRepository
{
    Task AddOrderAsync(Order Order);
    Task<Order?> GetOrderByIdAsync(int id);
    Task<IEnumerable<Order>> GetOrderByCustomerName(string name);
    Task<IEnumerable<Order>> GetOrderByVendorName(string name);
    Task UpdateOrderAsync(Order order);
}
public class OrderRepository : IOrderRepository
    {
        private readonly IMSContext _db;
        
        public OrderRepository(IMSContext db)
        {
            this._db = db;
           
        }

        public async Task AddOrderAsync(Order order)
        {
            
            if (_db.Orders.Any(x =>
                    x.Id == order.Id)) return;

            this._db.Orders.Add(order);

            await this._db.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        public async Task<Order?> GetOrderByIdAsync(int id)
        {
            return await this._db.Orders.FindAsync(id);
        }
        public async Task<IEnumerable<Order>> GetOrderByCustomerName(string name)
        {
            return await this._db.Orders.Where(x => x.CustomerName.ToLower().IndexOf(name.ToLower()) >= 0).ToListAsync();
        }
        public async Task<IEnumerable<Order>> GetOrderByVendorName(string name)
        {
            return await this._db.Orders.Where(x => x.VendorName.ToLower().IndexOf(name.ToLower()) >= 0).ToListAsync();
        }
        public async Task UpdateOrderAsync(Order order)
        {
            if (_db.Orders.Any(x =>
                    x.Id != order.Id)) return;

            var ord = await this._db.Orders.FindAsync(order.Id);
            if (ord != null)
            {
                ord.CustomerName = order.CustomerName;
                ord.VendorName = order.VendorName;
                ord.Status = order.Status;
                ord.OrderDateTime = order.OrderDateTime;
                ord.OrderDetails = order.OrderDetails;
               
                await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
        }
    }
 public class EditOrderUseCase: IEditOrderUseCase
    {
        private readonly IOrderRepository _orderRepository;

        public EditOrderUseCase(IOrderRepository orderRepository)
        {
            this._orderRepository = orderRepository;
        }

        public async Task ExecuteAsync(Order order)
        {
            await _orderRepository.UpdateOrderAsync(order);
        }
    }
public class AddOrderUseCase : IAddOrderUseCase
    {
        private readonly IOrderRepository _orderRepository;

        public AddOrderUseCase(IOrderRepository orderRepository)
        {
            this._orderRepository = orderRepository;
        }
        public async Task ExecuteAsync(Order order)
        {
            await _orderRepository.AddOrderAsync(order);
        }
    }
```

Here is the master-detail Blazor page I am trying to implement. I think I am a little bit lost while implementing the master-detail page. I want to add both new order and order details when the user clicks the **Add New Order** button. The user can edit only orders or order details (more than one row can be edited for details) or both.
Would you please guide me to make this work?

Here is the Blazor page:

```
@page "/orders"
@using IMS.CoreBusiness
@using IMS.UseCases.Interfaces.Order


@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
@inject IViewOrdersByCustomerNameUseCase ViewOrdersByCustomerNameUseCase
@inject IAddOrderUseCase AddOrderUseCase
@inject IEditOrderUseCase EditOrderUseCase

<h1>Orders</h1>
<RadzenButton Icon="add_circle_outline" style="margin-bottom: 10px" Text="Add New Order" Click="@InsertRow" Disabled=@(orderToInsert != null) />
    <RadzenDataGrid @ref="grid" AllowFiltering="true" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="5" AllowSorting="true" RowRender="@RowRender" ExpandMode="DataGridExpandMode.Multiple"
                Data="@_orders" TItem="Order" EditMode="DataGridEditMode.Multiple" RowUpdate="@OnUpdateRow" RowCreate="@OnCreateRow">
        <Template Context="order">
            <RadzenCard Style="margin-bottom:20px">
                Company:
                <b>@order.VendorName</b>
            </RadzenCard>
            <RadzenTabs>
                <Tabs>
                    <RadzenTabsItem Text="Order Details">
                        <RadzenDataGrid AllowFiltering="true" AllowPaging="true" AllowSorting="true" Data="@(_orders.FirstOrDefault()?.OrderDetails)" TItem="OrderDetail" 
                                        EditMode="DataGridEditMode.Multiple" >
                            <Columns>
                                <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="OrderDetail" Property="Id" Title="Product Number" />
                                <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="OrderDetail" Property="ProductCode" Title="Code" />
                                <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="OrderDetail" Property="ProductName" Title="Name">
                                    <Template Context="detail">
                                        @String.Format(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"), "{0:C}",detail.UnitCost)
                                    </Template>
                                </RadzenDataGridColumn>
                                <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="OrderDetail" Property="BuyQuantity" Title="Buy Qty" />
                                <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="OrderDetail" Property="SellQuantity" Title="Sell Qty" />
                                <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="OrderDetail" Property="ShippingNumber" Title="Shipment"/>
                            </Columns>
                        </RadzenDataGrid>
                    </RadzenTabsItem>
                    
                </Tabs>
            </RadzenTabs>
        </Template>
        <Columns>
            <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="Order" Property="Id" Title="Order ID" Width="120px" />
            <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="Order" Property="CustomerName" Title="Customer" Width="200px" />
            <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="Order" Property="OrderDateTime" Title="Order Date" Width="200px">
                <Template Context="order">
                    @String.Format("{0:d}", order.OrderDateTime)
                </Template>
            </RadzenDataGridColumn>
            <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="Order" Property="Status" Title="Status" Width="100px" />
            <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="Order" Property="DoneBy" Title="Employee" />
            <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="Order" Context="order" Filterable="false" Sortable="false" TextAlign="TextAlign.Center" Width="120px">
                <Template Context="order">
                    <RadzenButton Icon="edit" ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Light" Class="m-1" Click="@(args => EditRow(order))" @onclick:stopPropagation="true">
                    </RadzenButton>
                </Template>
                <EditTemplate Context="order">
                    <RadzenButton Icon="check" ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Primary" Class="m-1" Click="@((args) => SaveRow(order))">
                    </RadzenButton>
                    <RadzenButton Icon="close" ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Light" Class="m-1" Click="@((args) => CancelEdit(order))">
                    </RadzenButton>
                </EditTemplate>
            </RadzenDataGridColumn>
            <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="Order" Context="order" Filterable="false" Sortable="false" TextAlign="TextAlign.Center" Width="60px">
                <Template Context="order">
                    <RadzenButton ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Danger" Icon="delete" Size="ButtonSize.Small" Class="m-1" Click="@(args => DeleteRow(order))"  @onclick:stopPropagation="true">
                    </RadzenButton>
                </Template>
                <EditTemplate Context="order">
                    <RadzenButton ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Danger" Icon="delete" Size="ButtonSize.Small" Class="m-1" Click="@(args => DeleteRow(order))">
                    </RadzenButton>
                </EditTemplate>
            </RadzenDataGridColumn>
        </Columns>
    </RadzenDataGrid>
@code {
   
    IEnumerable<Order> _orders = new List<Order>();
    
    RadzenDataGrid<Order> grid;
    Order orderToInsert;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        _orders = await ViewOrdersByCustomerNameUseCase.ExecuteAsync();

    }

    void RowRender(RowRenderEventArgs<Order> args)
    {
        if(args.Data.OrderDetails != null)
            args.Expandable = args.Data.OrderDetails.Count > 0;
    }

    protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            grid.ExpandRow(_orders.FirstOrDefault());
            StateHasChanged();
        }

        base.OnAfterRender(firstRender);
    }
    

    private async Task InsertRow()
    {
        orderToInsert = new Order();
        await grid.InsertRow(orderToInsert);
    }

    private async Task OnCreateRow(Order order)
    {
        if (order != null)
        {
            await AddOrderUseCase.ExecuteAsync(order);

        }

    
    }
    private async Task OnCreateRowDetail(Order order)
    {
        if (order != null)
        {
            await AddOrderUseCase.ExecuteAsync(order);

        }

    
    }
    private async Task OnUpdateRow(Order order)
    {
        if (order == orderToInsert)
        {
            orderToInsert = null;
        }

        if (order != null)
        {
            await EditOrderUseCase.ExecuteAsync(order);
           
        }
    }
    private async Task OnUpdateRowDetail(Order order)
    {
        if (order.OrderDetails != null)
        {
            await EditOrderUseCase.ExecuteAsync(order);
           
        }
    }

    private void CancelEdit(Order order)
    {
        if (order == orderToInsert)
        {
            orderToInsert = null;
        }

        grid.CancelEditRow(order);

    
    }

    async Task DeleteRow(Order order)
    {
        if (order == orderToInsert)
        {
            orderToInsert = null;
        }

        if (_orders.Contains(order))
        {
           await grid.Reload();
        }
        else
        {
            grid.CancelEditRow(order);
        }
    }
    async Task EditRow(Order order)
    {
        await grid.EditRow(order);
    }
    async Task SaveRow(Order order)
    {
        if (order == orderToInsert)
        {
            orderToInsert = null;
        }

        await grid.UpdateRow(order);
    }  

}
```

### [image]
Edit 3

I think I've figured it out a little so far about Radzen and master-detail grids. But still need some help.

Here is the updated and generally working Blazor:

```
@page "/orders"
@using IMS.CoreBusiness
@using IMS.Plugins.EFCore.Migrations
@using IMS.UseCases.Interfaces.Order
@using IMS.UseCases.Interfaces.OrderDetail


@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
@inject IViewAllOrdersUseCase ViewAllOrdersUseCase
@inject IAddOrderUseCase AddOrderUseCase
@inject IEditOrderUseCase EditOrderUseCase
@inject IAddOrderDetailUseCase AddOrderDetailUseCase
@inject IEditOrderDetailUseCase EditOrderDetailUseCase

<h1>Orders</h1>
<RadzenButton Icon="add_circle_outline" style="margin-bottom: 10px" Text="Add New Order" Click="@InsertRow" Disabled=@(orderToInsert != null) />
    <RadzenDataGrid @ref="grid" AllowFiltering="true" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="5" AllowSorting="true" RowRender="@RowRender" ExpandMode="DataGridExpandMode.Multiple"
                Data="@_orders" TItem="Order" EditMode="DataGridEditMode.Multiple" RowUpdate="@OnUpdateRow" RowCreate="@OnCreateRow">
        <Template Context="order">
            <RadzenCard Style="margin-bottom:20px">
                Vendor:
                <b>@order.VendorName</b>
            </RadzenCard>
            <RadzenTabs>
                <Tabs>
                    <RadzenTabsItem Text="Order Details">
                        <RadzenDataGrid @ref="gridDetail" AllowFiltering="true" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="5" AllowSorting="true" Data="@(_orders.FirstOrDefault()?.OrderDetails)" 
                        TItem="OrderDetail" EditMode="DataGridEditMode.Multiple" RowUpdate="@OnUpdateRowDetail" RowCreate="@OnCreateRowDetail" RowRender="@RowRenderDetail">
                            <Columns>
                                <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="OrderDetail" Property="Id" Title="Product Number" />
                                <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="OrderDetail" Property="ProductCode" Title="Code" />
                                <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="OrderDetail" Property="ProductName" Title="Name">
                                    <EditTemplate Context="orderDetail">
                                        <RadzenTextBox @bind-Value="orderDetail.ProductName" Style="width:100%; display: block" Name="ProductName" />
                                        <RadzenRequiredValidator Text="Product Name is required" Component="ProductName" Popup="true" Style="position:absolute"/>
                                    </EditTemplate>
                                </RadzenDataGridColumn>
                                <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="OrderDetail" Property="UnitCost" Title="Unit Cost">
                                    <Template Context="detail">
                                        @String.Format(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"), "{0:C}",detail.UnitCost)
                                    </Template>
                                </RadzenDataGridColumn>
                                <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="OrderDetail" Property="BuyQuantity" Title="Buy Qty" />
                                <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="OrderDetail" Property="SellQuantity" Title="Sell Qty" />
                                <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="OrderDetail" Property="ShippingNumber" Title="Shipment"/>
                                <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="OrderDetail" Context="order" Filterable="false" Sortable="false" TextAlign="TextAlign.Center" Width="60px">
                                    <Template Context="detail">
                                        <RadzenButton Icon="edit" ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Primary" Class="m-1" Click="@(args => EditRowDetail(detail))" @onclick:stopPropagation="true">
                                        </RadzenButton>
                                    </Template>
                                    <EditTemplate Context="detail">
                                        <RadzenButton Icon="check" ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Primary" Class="m-1" Click="@((args) => SaveRowDetail(detail))">
                                        </RadzenButton>
                                        <RadzenButton Icon="close" ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Light" Class="m-1" Click="@((args) => CancelEditDetail(detail))">
                                        </RadzenButton>
                                    </EditTemplate>
                                </RadzenDataGridColumn>
                            </Columns>
                        </RadzenDataGrid>
                    </RadzenTabsItem>
                    
                </Tabs>
            </RadzenTabs>
        </Template>
        <Columns>
            <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="Order" Property="Id" Title="Order ID" Width="120px" />
            <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="Order" Property="CustomerName" Title="Customer" Width="200px">
                <EditTemplate Context="order">
                    <RadzenTextBox @bind-Value="order.CustomerName" Style="width:100%; display: block" Name="CustomerName" />
                    <RadzenRequiredValidator Text="Customer Name is required" Component="CustomerName" Popup="true" Style="position:absolute"/>
                </EditTemplate>
            </RadzenDataGridColumn>
            <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="Order" Property="OrderDateTime" Title="Order Date" Width="200px">
                <Template Context="order">
                    @String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", order.OrderDateTime)
                </Template>
                <EditTemplate Context="order">
                    <RadzenDatePicker @bind-Value="order.OrderDateTime" Style="width:100%" DateFormat="d" />
                </EditTemplate>
            </RadzenDataGridColumn>
            <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="Order" Property="Status" Title="Status" Width="100px" />
            <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="Order" Property="DoneBy" Title="Employee">
                <EditTemplate Context="order">
                    <RadzenTextBox @bind-Value="order.DoneBy" Style="width:100%; display: block" Name="DoneBy" />
                    <RadzenRequiredValidator Text="DoneBy is required" Component="DoneBy" Popup="true" Style="position:absolute"/>
                </EditTemplate>
            </RadzenDataGridColumn>
            <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="Order" Context="order" Filterable="false" Sortable="false" TextAlign="TextAlign.Center" Width="120px">
                <Template Context="order">
                    <RadzenButton Icon="edit" ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Primary" Class="m-1" Click="@(args => EditRow(order))" @onclick:stopPropagation="true">
                    </RadzenButton>
                </Template>
                <EditTemplate Context="order">
                    <RadzenButton Icon="check" ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Primary" Class="m-1" Click="@((args) => SaveRow(order))">
                    </RadzenButton>
                    <RadzenButton Icon="close" ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Light" Class="m-1" Click="@((args) => CancelEdit(order))">
                    </RadzenButton>
                </EditTemplate>
            </RadzenDataGridColumn>
            @*<RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="Order" Context="order" Filterable="false" Sortable="false" TextAlign="TextAlign.Center" Width="60px">
                <Template Context="order">
                    <RadzenButton ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Danger" Icon="delete" Size="ButtonSize.Small" Class="m-1" Click="@(args => DeleteRow(order))"  @onclick:stopPropagation="true">
                    </RadzenButton>
                </Template>
                <EditTemplate Context="order">
                    <RadzenButton ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Danger" Icon="delete" Size="ButtonSize.Small" Class="m-1" Click="@(args => DeleteRow(order))">
                    </RadzenButton>
                </EditTemplate>
            </RadzenDataGridColumn>*@
        </Columns>
    </RadzenDataGrid>
@code {

    IEnumerable<Order> _orders = new List<Order>();
    IEnumerable<OrderDetail> _orderDetails = new List<OrderDetail>();
    
    RadzenDataGrid<Order> grid;
    RadzenDataGrid<OrderDetail> gridDetail;

    Order orderToInsert;
    OrderDetail detailToInsert;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        _orders = await ViewAllOrdersUseCase.ExecuteAsync();

    }

    void RowRender(RowRenderEventArgs<Order> args)
    {
        if(args.Data.OrderDetails != null)
            args.Expandable = args.Data.OrderDetails.Count > 0;
    }

    void RowRenderDetail(RowRenderEventArgs<OrderDetail> args)
    {
        if(args.Data != null)
            args.Expandable = true;
    }

    protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            grid.ExpandRow(_orders.FirstOrDefault());
            StateHasChanged();
        }

        base.OnAfterRender(firstRender);
    }


    private async Task InsertRow()
    {
        orderToInsert = new Order();
        detailToInsert = new OrderDetail();
        await grid.InsertRow(orderToInsert);
        await gridDetail.InsertRow(detailToInsert);
    }

    private async Task OnCreateRow(Order order)
    {
        if (order != null)
        {
            await AddOrderUseCase.ExecuteAsync(order);

        }


    }
    private async Task OnCreateRowDetail(OrderDetail orderDetail)
    {
        if (orderDetail != null)
        {
            await AddOrderDetailUseCase.ExecuteAsync(orderDetail);

        }


    }
    private async Task OnUpdateRow(Order order)
    {
        if (order == orderToInsert)
        {
            orderToInsert = null;
        }

        if (order != null)
        {
            await EditOrderUseCase.ExecuteAsync(order);

        }
    }
    private async Task OnUpdateRowDetail(OrderDetail orderDetail)
    {
        if (orderDetail == detailToInsert)
        {
            detailToInsert = null;
        }
        if (orderDetail != null)
        {
            await EditOrderDetailUseCase.ExecuteAsync(orderDetail);

        }
    }

    private void CancelEdit(Order order)
    {
        if (order == orderToInsert)
        {
            orderToInsert = null;
        }

        grid.CancelEditRow(order);


    }
    private void CancelEditDetail(OrderDetail orderDetail)
    {
        if (orderDetail == detailToInsert)
        {
            detailToInsert = null;
        }

        gridDetail.CancelEditRow(orderDetail);


    }

    async Task DeleteRow(Order order)
    {
        if (order == orderToInsert)
        {
            orderToInsert = null;
        }

        if (_orders.Contains(order))
        {
            await grid.Reload();
        }
        else
        {
            grid.CancelEditRow(order);
        }
    }

    async Task DeleteRowDetail(OrderDetail orderDetail)
    {
        if (orderDetail == detailToInsert)
        {
            detailToInsert = null;
        }


        if (_orders.All(x=>x.OrderDetails.Contains(orderDetail)))
        {
            await gridDetail.Reload();
        }
        else
        {
            gridDetail.CancelEditRow(orderDetail);
        }
    }
    async Task EditRow(Order order)
    {
        await grid.EditRow(order);
    }

    async Task EditRowDetail(OrderDetail orderDetail)
    {
        await gridDetail.EditRow(orderDetail);
    }
    async Task SaveRow(Order order)
    {
        if (order == orderToInsert)
        {
            orderToInsert = null;
        }

        await grid.UpdateRow(order);
    }

    async Task SaveRowDetail(OrderDetail orderDetail)
    {
        if (orderDetail == detailToInsert)
        {
            detailToInsert = null;
        }

        await gridDetail.UpdateRow(orderDetail);
    }
   

}
```

Here are the issues that I expect support from you in order to succeed.

1. When trying to add a new row, I don't want the date (1.01.0001) just the calendar icon.
   [image]
2. Why is there no cancel button when I click the inner grid edit button?
   [image]
3. Why not add a new row to the inner grid when I click Add New Row?
   [image]

Comment: Could you please share the code that you are ended with so far? So that it would be great to check your snippet feasibility and help you to assist further.

Comment: Hi @MdFaridUddinKiron Thank you for your reply. I added the current status, hope someone can help me.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron can you check my updated code please?

Comment: Thanks for sharing are you using any UI tool? Which one?

Comment: I fixed the problems, will update the post.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problems fixed code:

```
@page "/orders"
@using IMS.CoreBusiness
@using IMS.Plugins.EFCore.Migrations
@using IMS.UseCases.Interfaces.Order
@using IMS.UseCases.Interfaces.OrderDetail


@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
@inject IViewAllOrdersUseCase ViewAllOrdersUseCase
@inject IAddOrderUseCase AddOrderUseCase
@inject IEditOrderUseCase EditOrderUseCase
@inject IAddOrderDetailUseCase AddOrderDetailUseCase
@inject IEditOrderDetailUseCase EditOrderDetailUseCase

<h1>Orders</h1>
<RadzenButton Icon="add_circle_outline" style="margin-bottom: 10px" Text="Add New Order" Click="@InsertRow" Disabled=@(orderToInsert != null) />
    <RadzenDataGrid @ref="grid" AllowFiltering="true" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="5" AllowSorting="true" RowRender="@RowRender" ExpandMode="DataGridExpandMode.Multiple"
                Data="@_orders" TItem="Order" EditMode="DataGridEditMode.Multiple" RowUpdate="@OnUpdateRow" RowCreate="@OnCreateRow" @bind-Value="@SelectedOrders">
        <Template Context="order">
            <RadzenCard Style="margin-bottom:20px">
                Vendor:
                <b>@order.VendorName</b>
            </RadzenCard>
            <RadzenTabs>
                <Tabs>
                    <RadzenTabsItem Text="Order Details">
                        <RadzenButton Icon="add_circle_outline" style="margin-bottom: 10px" Text="Add Order Detail" Click="@InsertDetailRow" Disabled=@(detailToInsert != null) />
                        <RadzenDataGrid @ref="gridDetail" AllowFiltering="true" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="5" AllowSorting="true" Data="@(SelectedOrders.FirstOrDefault()?.OrderDetails)" 
                        TItem="OrderDetail" EditMode="DataGridEditMode.Multiple" RowUpdate="@OnUpdateRowDetail" RowCreate="@OnCreateRowDetail" RowRender="@RowRenderDetail">
                            <Columns>
                                <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="OrderDetail" Property="Id" Title="Product Number" />
                                <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="OrderDetail" Property="ProductCode" Title="Code">
                                    <EditTemplate Context="orderDetail">
                                        <RadzenTextBox @bind-Value="orderDetail.ProductCode" Style="width:100%; display: block" Name="ProductCode" />
                                        <RadzenRequiredValidator Text="Product Code is required" Component="ProductCode" Popup="true" Style="position:absolute"/>
                                    </EditTemplate>
                                </RadzenDataGridColumn>
                                <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="OrderDetail" Property="ProductName" Title="Name">
                                    <EditTemplate Context="orderDetail">
                                        <RadzenTextBox @bind-Value="orderDetail.ProductName" Style="width:100%; display: block" Name="ProductName" />
                                        <RadzenRequiredValidator Text="Product Name is required" Component="ProductName" Popup="true" Style="position:absolute"/>
                                    </EditTemplate>
                                </RadzenDataGridColumn>
                                <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="OrderDetail" Property="UnitCost" Title="Unit Cost">
                                    <Template Context="detail">
                                        @String.Format(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"), "{0:C}",detail.UnitCost)
                                    </Template>
                                    @*<EditTemplate Context="orderDetail">
                                        <RadzenNumeric ShowUpDown="false" TValue="double?" @bind-Value="orderDetail.UnitCost" Class="w-100" />
                                        @*<RadzenTextBox @bind-Value="orderDetail.UnitCost" Style="width:100%; display: block" Name="UnitCost" />
                                        <RadzenRequiredValidator Text="Unit Cost is required" Component="UnitCost" Popup="true" Style="position:absolute"/>
                                    </EditTemplate>*@
                                </RadzenDataGridColumn>
                                <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="OrderDetail" Property="BuyQuantity" Title="Buy Qty" />
                                <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="OrderDetail" Property="SellQuantity" Title="Sell Qty" />
                                <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="OrderDetail" Property="ShippingNumber" Title="Shipment"/>
                                <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="OrderDetail" Context="orderDetail" Filterable="false" Sortable="false" TextAlign="TextAlign.Center" Width="120px">
                                    <Template Context="detail">
                                        <RadzenButton Icon="edit" ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Primary" Class="m-1" Click="@(args => EditRowDetail(detail))" @onclick:stopPropagation="true">
                                        </RadzenButton>
                                    </Template>
                                    <EditTemplate Context="detail">
                                        <RadzenButton Icon="check" ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Primary" Class="m-1" Click="@((args) => SaveRowDetail(detail))">
                                        </RadzenButton>
                                        <RadzenButton Icon="close" ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Light" Class="m-1" Click="@((args) => CancelEditDetail(detail))">
                                        </RadzenButton>
                                    </EditTemplate>
                                </RadzenDataGridColumn>
                            </Columns>
                        </RadzenDataGrid>
                    </RadzenTabsItem>
                    
                </Tabs>
            </RadzenTabs>
        </Template>
        <Columns>
            <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="Order" Property="Id" Title="Order ID" Width="120px" />
            <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="Order" Property="CustomerName" Title="Customer" Width="200px">
                <EditTemplate Context="order">
                    <RadzenTextBox @bind-Value="order.CustomerName" Style="width:100%; display: block" Name="CustomerName" />
                    <RadzenRequiredValidator Text="Customer Name is required" Component="CustomerName" Popup="true" Style="position:absolute"/>
                </EditTemplate>
            </RadzenDataGridColumn>
            <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="Order" Property="OrderDateTime" Title="Order Date" Width="200px">
                <Template Context="order">
                    @String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", order.OrderDateTime)
                </Template>
                <EditTemplate Context="order">
                    <RadzenDatePicker TValue="DateTime?" DateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm" Class="w-100" />
                    @*<RadzenDatePicker @bind-Value="order.OrderDateTime" Style="width:100%" DateFormat="d" />*@
                </EditTemplate>
            </RadzenDataGridColumn>
            <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="Order" Property="Status" Title="Status" Width="100px">
                <EditTemplate Context="order">
                    <RadzenTextBox @bind-Value="order.Status" Style="width:100%; display: block" Name="Status" />
                    <RadzenRequiredValidator Text="Status is required" Component="Status" Popup="true" Style="position:absolute"/>
                </EditTemplate>
            </RadzenDataGridColumn>
            <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="Order" Property="DoneBy" Title="Employee">
                <EditTemplate Context="order">
                    <RadzenTextBox @bind-Value="order.DoneBy" Style="width:100%; display: block" Name="DoneBy" />
                    <RadzenRequiredValidator Text="DoneBy is required" Component="DoneBy" Popup="true" Style="position:absolute"/>
                </EditTemplate>
            </RadzenDataGridColumn>
            <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="Order" Context="order" Filterable="false" Sortable="false" TextAlign="TextAlign.Center" Width="120px">
                <Template Context="order">
                    <RadzenButton Icon="edit" ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Primary" Class="m-1" Click="@(args => EditRow(order))" @onclick:stopPropagation="true">
                    </RadzenButton>
                </Template>
                <EditTemplate Context="order">
                    <RadzenButton Icon="check" ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Primary" Class="m-1" Click="@((args) => SaveRow(order))">
                    </RadzenButton>
                    <RadzenButton Icon="close" ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Light" Class="m-1" Click="@((args) => CancelEdit(order))">
                    </RadzenButton>
                </EditTemplate>
            </RadzenDataGridColumn>
            @*<RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="Order" Context="order" Filterable="false" Sortable="false" TextAlign="TextAlign.Center" Width="60px">
                <Template Context="order">
                    <RadzenButton ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Danger" Icon="delete" Size="ButtonSize.Small" Class="m-1" Click="@(args => DeleteRow(order))"  @onclick:stopPropagation="true">
                    </RadzenButton>
                </Template>
                <EditTemplate Context="order">
                    <RadzenButton ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Danger" Icon="delete" Size="ButtonSize.Small" Class="m-1" Click="@(args => DeleteRow(order))">
                    </RadzenButton>
                </EditTemplate>
            </RadzenDataGridColumn>*@
        </Columns>
    </RadzenDataGrid>
@code {
    IList<Order> SelectedOrders { get; set; }

    IEnumerable<Order> _orders = new List<Order>();

    RadzenDataGrid<Order> grid;
    RadzenDataGrid<OrderDetail> gridDetail;

    Order orderToInsert;
    OrderDetail detailToInsert;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        _orders = await ViewAllOrdersUseCase.ExecuteAsync();
        SelectedOrders = new List<Order>(){ _orders.FirstOrDefault() };

    }

    void RowRender(RowRenderEventArgs<Order> args)
    {
        if(args.Data.OrderDetails != null)
            args.Expandable = args.Data.OrderDetails.Count > 0;
    }

    void RowRenderDetail(RowRenderEventArgs<OrderDetail> args)
    {
        if(args.Data != null)
            args.Expandable = true;
    }

    protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            grid.ExpandRow(_orders.FirstOrDefault());
            StateHasChanged();
        }

        base.OnAfterRender(firstRender);
    }


    private async Task InsertRow()
    {
        orderToInsert = new Order();
        await grid.InsertRow(orderToInsert);
        
    }
    private async Task InsertDetailRow()
    {
        detailToInsert = new OrderDetail();
        await gridDetail.InsertRow(detailToInsert);
    }

    private async Task OnCreateRow(Order order)
    {
        if (order != null)
        {
            await AddOrderUseCase.ExecuteAsync(order);

        }


    }
    private async Task OnCreateRowDetail(OrderDetail orderDetail)
    {
        if (orderDetail != null)
        {
            await AddOrderDetailUseCase.ExecuteAsync(orderDetail);

        }


    }
    private async Task OnUpdateRow(Order order)
    {
        if (order == orderToInsert)
        {
            orderToInsert = null;
        }

        if (order != null)
        {
            await EditOrderUseCase.ExecuteAsync(order);

        }
    }
    private async Task OnUpdateRowDetail(OrderDetail orderDetail)
    {
        if (orderDetail == detailToInsert)
        {
            detailToInsert = null;
        }
        if (orderDetail != null)
        {
            await EditOrderDetailUseCase.ExecuteAsync(orderDetail);

        }
    }

    private void CancelEdit(Order order)
    {
        if (order == orderToInsert)
        {
            orderToInsert = null;
        }

        grid.CancelEditRow(order);


    }
    private void CancelEditDetail(OrderDetail orderDetail)
    {
        if (orderDetail == detailToInsert)
        {
            detailToInsert = null;
        }

        gridDetail.CancelEditRow(orderDetail);


    }

    async Task DeleteRow(Order order)
    {
        if (order == orderToInsert)
        {
            orderToInsert = null;
        }

        if (_orders.Contains(order))
        {
            await grid.Reload();
        }
        else
        {
            grid.CancelEditRow(order);
        }
    }

    async Task DeleteRowDetail(OrderDetail orderDetail)
    {
        if (orderDetail == detailToInsert)
        {
            detailToInsert = null;
        }


        if (_orders.All(x=>x.OrderDetails.Contains(orderDetail)))
        {
            await gridDetail.Reload();
        }
        else
        {
            gridDetail.CancelEditRow(orderDetail);
        }
    }
    async Task EditRow(Order order)
    {
        await grid.EditRow(order);
    }

    async Task EditRowDetail(OrderDetail orderDetail)
    {
        await gridDetail.EditRow(orderDetail);
    }
    async Task SaveRow(Order order)
    {
        if (order == orderToInsert)
        {
            orderToInsert = null;
        }

        await grid.UpdateRow(order);
    }

    async Task SaveRowDetail(OrderDetail orderDetail)
    {
        if (orderDetail == detailToInsert)
        {
            detailToInsert = null;
        }

        await gridDetail.UpdateRow(orderDetail);
    }
   

}
```